# Is the async keyword required to create asynchronous functionality? Did this functionality change in the recent past?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, .net-framework-version

I'm attempting to show that it is possible for my team to add asynchronous functionality to a currently "fully-syncrhonous" program. Are there any reasons, such as requiring the async decorator, that the following code would not yield expected results if something similar were shoved into our production code?

**Code:**

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //TODO: Try to show that Tasks are async inside of sync methods
            var waitForStuff = Task.Run(() => stuff());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("In between stuff- From Main");
            //waitForStuff.Wait(); - This wait doesn't even appear to be necessary
            var result = waitForStuff.Result;
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = "Main didn't wait for task";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        
        private static string stuff(){
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning of Stuff");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("End of Stuff");
            return "stuff";
        }
```

**Console:**

```
Beginning of Stuff
In between stuff- From Main
End of Stuff
stuff
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your question is. `async` is required in order to use the `await` keyword. Accessing `.Result` will block until the Task is complete, so does the same thing as calling `.Wait()`

Comment: @canton7, sorry, I'm having a hard time articulating what I'm trying to ask. This question is just as vauge, but maybe it's beter... :  Is there any reason this code wouldn't be giving "true" async functionality?

Comment: It depends on how you define "true" async functionality. The main thread can do things while `stuff` is executing (like printing that "In between stuff" message). However, the main thread isn't released to go and do work in other methods, which is what "async" normally means in C# these days

Comment: `await` means "I have no useful work to do until whatever is to the right of that has finished". Note, importantly, it doesn't know/care about how that thing to the right has come into existence, nor how it will complete its job.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "*asynchronous functionality*" and "*expected results*"?

Your code waits for the result of a **non**-async method because the type it's returning (`Task`) is awaitable. But it isn't using the normal [task asynchronous pattern](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) and the `async` / `await` keywords.

The `async` keyword applied to a method enables the `await` keyword in that method. Then the `await` keyword examines the awaitable (eg `Task`) argument. If the awaitable has completed, the method just runs synchronously. If the awaitable hasn't completed, the method returns immediately but tells the awaitable to run the rest of the method after task completion.

So in your context:

```
var waitForStuff = Stuff();

public async Task<string> Stuff()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Beginning of Stuff");
   await Task.Delay(5000);
   Console.WriteLine("End of Stuff");
   return "stuff";
}
```

You should be aware of [how to use async/await properly in console programs](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html).

Comment: *"What do you mean by "asynchronous functionality" and "expected results"?"* -- This question should probably be a comment under the OP's question!